# how to solve Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

Tags: android, drawer

I wanted to add navigation drawer for  to my app so I created new activity and I wrote this code on class java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    Toolbar toolbar=null;
    NavigationView navigationView=null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container,fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {



        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

and this is what I'm writing on layout activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Layout nav_header_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="160dp"

    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:text="text text"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="190dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="255dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

app_bar_main.xml

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container">

    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"

        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and this is my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0 rc3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mstr.malik.shopingapps"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'

}
```

Here is the error I get:

```
05-11 11:37:26.042 3116-3116/com.mstr.malik.shopingapps E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: com.mstr.malik.shopingapps, PID: 3116
                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mstr.malik.shopingapps/com.mstr.malik.shopingapps.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                           Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
                                                                              at com.mstr.malik.shopingapps.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256)
```

Comment: add your style.xml

Comment: post you manifest file.... you are adding the API Key to your application???

Comment: did you used android:textColorPrimary in style.xml?

Answer (score 0):

try to change activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In your themes.xml file you must remove this line:

```
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">#fff</item>
```

Once it's removed the app won't crash anymore.